# Why is the Index of a Pandas DataFrame Slice different to its shape?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a DataFrame, `df1`, which is a slice of `df`. `df` is multiindexed and has shape `(8,)`. The slice removes some of the second level of `df`. When I do `df1.shape` it returns `(4,)` - all good - but when I do `df1.index.levels[0]` this returns `(4,)`. How come this happens?

```
In [ ]:       
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
            np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]


    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,2), index=arrays)
    df

Out [ ]:
            0        1
bar one   -0.447155  -0.323073
    two    0.115899  -0.015561
baz one   -0.272498  1.847073
    two   -0.399948  -0.264327
foo one    0.169687  -1.708543
    two    1.154434  0.878936
qux one    0.535721  0.437186
    two   -1.203431  0.568412

In [ ]:
    df1=df[df[1]>0]

Out [ ]:
            0           1
    baz one  -0.272498  1.847073
    foo two  1.154434   0.878936
    qux one  0.535721   0.437186
        two  -1.203431  0.568412
```

Now for the weird bit

```
In [ ]:
    df1=df[df[1]>0]
    print(df1.index.levels[0], df1.index.levels[0].shape)

Out [ ]:
    Index(['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], dtype='object') (4,)
```

I find this strange as there is no `bar` shown in `df1`. What is the reason behind this?

*My guess is it is something to do with copying/not copying but I don't understand why.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#basic-indexing-on-axis-with-multiindex):

> Note The repr of a MultiIndex shows ALL the defined levels of an index, even if the they are not actually used. When slicing an index, you may notice this. ...
>
> This is done to avoid a recomputation of the levels in order to make slicing highly performant. If you want to see the actual used levels...

To reconstruct the multiindex with only the used levels

```
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df1.index)
```

Comment: I guess I didn't know enough about multiindexing to think to look there or know what to look for so many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the two indexes:

```
In [59]: df.index
Out[59]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]])

In [58]: df1.index
Out[58]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'bar', u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[1, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

When building `df1` with `df1 = df[df[1]>0]` Pandas can build `df1.index` by
merely changing the `labels`. Moreover, if it doesn't change the `levels`, then
it doesn't have to renumber the `labels`. This is why `df1.index` contains `bar`
even though `df1` doesn't use `bar`.

You can rebuild the index by using `reset_index/set_index`:

```
In [63]: df1.reset_index().set_index(['level_0', 'level_1']).index
Out[63]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'baz', u'foo', u'qux'], [u'one', u'two']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=[u'level_0', u'level_1'])
```

-- or use [Alexander's faster solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36629728/190597), `df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df1.index)` -- but Pandas
   doesn't do this by default probably for better performance.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the levels are just the labels, it's the second level values that determine which labels are present for that label, so for instance in my case:

```
In [2]:
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
            np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]
​
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8,2), index=arrays)
df
​
Out[2]:
                0         1
bar one  1.226303  0.017598
    two  0.940893  1.491474
baz one  0.335430  1.178512
    two -1.006346 -0.733090
foo one -0.765838 -0.494056
    two -1.744994 -1.001641
qux one  0.177123 -0.969671
    two  0.544314 -0.026114

In [3]:    
df1=df[df[1]>0]
df1.index

Out[3]:
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
```

gives:

```
In [4]:
df1

Out[4]:
                0         1
bar one  1.226303  0.017598
    two  0.940893  1.491474
baz one  0.335430  1.178512
```

So if you look at the index:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
               labels=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]])
```

the values: `labels=[[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]` are the values from the level values that are present which is why you see all 4 labels and the shape is 4

Comment: Just for clarity then, the first part labels `labels=[[0,0,1],...]` are equivalent to saying "the Multiindex level 0 is `['bar', 'bar', 'baz']`"?

Comment: Yes that's correct it's an index to reference the levels